# Regular expression

Tags: uitextfield, swift4.2

I want the user to enter text in a text field, and if the user types "<" a space should be automatically appended to the text in the field

I tried removing the special character but I need the user to input that as well.

```
let RISTRICTED_CHARACTERS = "<"
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: RISTRICTED_CHARACTERS)
let inverted = set.inverted
let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: inverted).joined(separator: "")
if filtered == string && string != "" {
   return false
} else {
    let maxLength = maxLenghtOfTextField
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

In this code I'm not allowing "<" this character. I want the text field to be like this.

My output should be `: hello <(space) world`.
The space should be automatically appended if I start with "<" sign.

Comment: Please edit to clearly state your question. It's not clear what the title has to do with the situation you present, or what the problem is, and that makes it likely that your question will be put on hold for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .replacingCharacters maybe try .replacingOccurences

```
let updatedString: String? = textField.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: " ")
```